# How to change home for solrcloud

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am new to Solrcloud. I want to set solr home directory to solr-7.6.0/home when I am run in solrcloud mode. But when I run ./solr start -e cloud, the home directory is created inside example directory. When I run ./solr start -c -s ../home, again  the home directory is created inside example folder. Is anything I have to put(like configuratio files) inside home directory before starting solrcloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the examples.

I suggest you set up a more realistic setup:

1. Download zookeeper and start it
2. Install Solr as a Service
3. Configure the Solr service to go into "cloud mode" by setting "ZK_HOST" in "solr.in.sh"
4. Set "SOLR_DATA_HOME" in "solr.in.sh"

Comment: Follow this step by step reference http://www.francelabs.com/blog/tutorial-deploying-solrcloud-7-on-amazon-ec2/